# Change rownames by using a function that I built in R

Tags: r, function, bioinformatics

I have several dataframes and I'm using the same code for all of them, which is why I decided to build some functions, to make the code more readable.

One function is switching from gene symbols to gene IDs. What the function does is recieve a dataset as input. At first it contains gene symbols as rownames, after the function it wil have gene IDs as rownames. Pretty basic.

The problem is, the function doesn't do what I need it to do. The `rownames` in the entered dataset stay the same after running the function.

The last line in the function, `rownames(dataset) <- geneIDs$GENEID`, is supposed to do that, it basically takes the column `GENEID`, which I just imported from the `ensembldb` package, and put it as `rownames` in the entered dataset.

Here is the code:

```
GetGeneID <- function(dataset) {
  
  geneSymbols = as.vector(rownames(dataset))
  geneIDs = ensembldb::select(EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86, keys= geneSymbols, keytype = "SYMBOL", columns = c("SYMBOL","GENEID"))
  dupli = duplicated(geneIDs$SYMBOL) 
  geneIDs = geneIDs[!dupli,]
  rownames(geneIDs) = geneIDs$SYMBOL
  ind <- intersect(rownames(geneIDs), rownames(dataset))
  dataset <- dataset[ind,]
  rownames(dataset) <- geneIDs$GENEID
  
}

GetGeneID (counts1)
```

And also tried `counts1 = GetGeneID(counts1)` but this doesn't work because of the length of rownames, it changes after running the function, some genes get deleted because they don't have any gene ID, so it return an error for length.

The code works just fine when it's not in a function, it gets the job done. So what did I do wrong? also adding `return` at the end did not help. Thanks!

Comment: You have to return `dataset`, put its name as the last function instruction.

Comment: Thanks! I just did that and it worked.